# JavaScript - Need help explaining why closure is not working

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to build a basic hangman game.  I'm trying to get 'runcode' function to run once using closures. However I'm not sure why my closure is not working.  I'm creating an object then using the map method to replace the letters with underscores.

```
const hangMan = () => {
  const word = "honduras";
  const arrayWord = word.split("");
  let dashedWord = [];

  const hashWord = () => {
    dashedWord = arrayWord.map((el, index) => {
      dashedWord.push(el);
      return (el = "_");
    });
    // console.log(`dashedword function = ${dashedWord}`);
    // return dashedWord;
  };

  // console.log(prevWord);
  // console.log(hashedWord);

  // console.log((arrayWord[0] = "t"));
  // console.log(arrayWord.indexOf("t"));
  // console.log(typeof arrayWord);
  // console.log(arrayWord);

  function findIndex(word, index) {
    return word.indexOf(index);
  }

  function updateFoundLetter(guess) {
    let executed = false;
    console.log("fired updateFoundLetter");

    const runcode = () => {
      console.log(`UpdateFoundLetter wordHashed = ${executed}`);
      if (!executed) {
        hashWord();
        executed = true;
        console.log("ran true");
      } else {
         let index = findIndex(word, guess);
        dashedWord[index] = guess;
      }

      //console.log("hashedword index " + dashedWord[index]);
      // console.log(index);
    };

    return runcode;
  }

  //console.log(`before calling updateFoundLetter ${wordHashed}`);
  let myFunc = updateFoundLetter("h", word);
  myFunc();

  console.log(dashedWord);

  //console.log(`after calling updateFoundLetter ${wordHashed}`);
  //console.log(findIndex(word, "o"));
};

hangMan();
```

Comment: Can you send us an error if there is one?

Comment: Thank you for responding! There is no error but after I run the hashWord() function, it's returning an new array.   So when I pass a new letter updateFoundLetter("o", word) it's not updating the dashedWord  array with the second found letter.  I need to only run the hasWord() function once, so i tried to use closures to achieve this however the value of the variable 'executed' is not holding on to true after its set.